# Nginx Hashing using query parameters

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have a system where I need to redirect requests from a single manager to different worker servers. I can use an nginx load balancer, but I need to ensure that subsequent requests for a particular user are sent to the same worker. I can't use ip-hashing as the api request will be from the single manager and hence same api. Can I use query parameters instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is 1 server which sends requests to 5 worker services hosted inside dockers. Each of these services have 4 endpoints for 4 tasks and the requirement is one of session persistence, i.e. if the first request for a user goes through worker service 1, the remaining 3 should also go through same container. Using load balancer, i can leverage ip hashing to redirect all requests from a client using ip hashing, this is not the case as i am using a single server to send requests. The request can be identified by uids which is part of query params. Can query params be used for server persistence.